# Searching users and showing user records in Plone

Tags: plone

I want to implement search functionality in plone. Search depending on users , users email. Want to display user full details. 
Is there any existing add on which I can use (or) I have to write my own code.

Comment: Plone provides search over content stored in Plone out of the box. Or what are actually searching for. Be specific instead of letting us guess what your read problem is.

Comment: I have edited the question. Want to search based on users name, email and want to display full details.

Comment: Users are not content and can not be search this way other through the build-in Plone user management,

Comment: /Members can search on users, /author/<userid> shows content created by that user. You can start from there to write your code. Try to search if the question is answered somewhere in plone-users.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Comment: I am new to plone. I didn't write code for search functionality. just want to implement some search functionalities. Got some sample search functionalities in plone.org site. will modify those search functionalites according to my requirements.Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Plone does not do "users by content" by default.

- User objects are not registered as content
- Thus, the standard Plone search functionality does not cover users

If you wish to make users visible for everyone and searchable

- There is add-on http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.remember/ which will turn users to content items and this serve some niche use cases
- Alternatively, you can write your own search box view like Users/Group page in Site setup does

If you need members to be public on your site I would suggest take a look on *Products.remember*. It will also give you the ability to extend user records through Archetypes content subsystem and make them subject to workflow menu (have different states for members like disabled, registered, etc.)

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/archetypes/index.html